# MediaWiki Scribunto extension's "Listen" module not generating expected HTML

Tags: lua, mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions, scribunto

I have a MediaWiki installation (1.23) with the Scribunto extension and Module:Listen. I try to invoke this module from an article like so:

```
{{Listen
 |filename     = Noise.ogg
 |title        = Noise
 |description  = Some noise
}}
```

This generates the little infobox, but the embedded sound player itself does not appear. I looked at the generated HTML, and the module is just making a second ordinary href to the file:

```
<div class="haudio">
<div style="padding:2px 0;"><a href="/wiki/File:Noise.ogg" title="File:Noise.ogg">Noise</a></div>
<div style="padding-right:4px;"><a href="/wiki/File:Noise.ogg" title="File:Noise.ogg">File:Noise.ogg</a></div>
<div class="description" style="padding:2px 0 0 0;">Some noise</div></div>
```

Rather than the second href to the file, I'd expect to see a  or similar. Am I missing some template or Lua module?

Comment: Do you have [TimedMediaHandler](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:TimedMediaHandler) installed?

Comment: I don't have TimedMediaHandler, but it looks like this is a separate extension. Unless I'm mistaken, I don't think Scribunto or Module:Listen depend on it.

Comment: They don't, but you need it for the sound player to show up!

Comment: Ah, so you do -- I just installed TimedMediaHandler (and MwEmbedSupport, on which it depends) and it's now working. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have [TimedMediaHandler](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:TimedMediaHandler) installed for the sound player to show up!